# How can I disable the shadow around a window?

Tags: window-decoration

All the unmaximised windows on elementary OS have a shadow around them.

This causes issues with me taking screenshots. How can I disable the shadow when it isn't maximised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do that, that I know of. Shadows are drawn by the toolkit (Gtk+). You can edit your system stylesheet (located at `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css`) and remove the `box-shadow` from all `window-frame` classes. But be aware that the box shadow property also effects the *inner* shadow i.e. highlighting.

Comment: @Tim Those only effect the legacy server-side decorations. Most new apps will be using client-side decorations