# How to remove the window header or decorations?

Tags: design, window-decoration

**TL;DR:** I would like to have the same thing as described [here](http://erenon.hu/2013/04/03/slick-gnome-terminal/), but for Elementary OS.

I want to have the (graphical) terminal and Emacs windows the header or without any decorations. Does anyone know how to do this?

Off topic, but indirectly related: I see a little to no use of the border and the headers of the windows. Fortunately, elementary OS puts acceptable borders on the windows, but the header is still a disaster. The header info could appear on mouse-over or in the common header line like it is done in OSX.
If there is any movement in this or similar direction, please let me know.

P.S. Emacs works not inside the terminal.

P.P.S. I see that [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-disable-the-shadow-around-a-window) is a little bit related, but I cannot figure out how to reach the expected result.

**UPDATE:** This is in fact a final answer on initial question, but I don't want to add another one as Daniel Foré has already provided the acceptable answer.
I changed the source code so that decorations and scrollbar are disabled (thanks Daniel!), but the problem is a bit deeper: it is necessary to do something with tabs, but it seems the terminal simply needs another, "naked" mode which would disable everything plus setting the terminal into the single window mode (no invisible tabs).
For those who are interested, it was only `set_decorated(false);` in function `init`, about line 123 in file PantheonTerminalWindow.vala and also I disabled the scrollbar commenting out the line `g.attach (sb, 1, 0, 1, 1)` (line number about 579). The hack is dirty, but it was good enough to see that disabling the decorations is just not enough. Alas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really possible without forking the application. Decorations are drawn by the toolkit now instead of by the window manager which means that they are actually part of the application and not something separate.

Comment: Do I understand right that the paradigm changed? The responsibility of all decorations *except for the shadow* went to the app itself?

Comment: @avp even the shadow (the window frame) is drawn by the toolkit (which means the app itself draws it).

Comment: @DanielForé is there any chance this might be changed in the future?

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 No, sorry